# Vuetify: reserve space for scrollbars

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scrollbar, vuetify.js, overflow

I have a `<v-navigation-drawer>` which contains multiple `<v-cards>`. When clicking on a button, more cards appear and they overflow the screen; there's thus a scrollbar that appears. The problem is that this changes the width of the cards, which makes the transition look quite bad.

Is there a way to already reserve space for the scrollbar, or to overlay it on top of the card rather than making it change the width of the card?
I already tried playing with `overflow-y`, but haven't found any one working...

[Before clicking on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw164.png)

[After clicking on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ehil.png)

Here is a sample code for my problem:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-navigation-drawer app left width="450" clipped>
      <v-card>
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/875996174305472512/upM71pVR.jpg" />
      </v-card>
      <v-card>
        <v-btn @click="showImage = !showImage">Show Image</v-btn>
      </v-card>
      <v-card v-if="showImage">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/b4/8b/5bb48b07fa6e3840bb3afa2bc821b882.jpg" />
      </v-card>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TopBar",
  data: () => ({
    showImage: false
  })
};
</script>
```

Comment: that's odd ... I've had to disable the scroll bar when using vuetify, because vuetify forces it on - but then, I do use `<v-app>` which I think triggers that ... and you've shown the code for your topbar - where's your main vue?

Comment: anyway, try adding `html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}`